# A website which lists problems a software developer or data scientist can work on?

Tags: web

A website which lists problems a software developer or data scientist can work on ?

Basically one of my friend who is in infrastructure want to learn data scienece, so I am looking for cool projects for him to work on...

But I am trying to find a website where people come up with ideas and need help vounteerily

Answer (score 3):

If you are into R, then check out [TidyTuesday](https://github.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday)

> The intent of Tidy Tuesday is to provide a safe and supportive forum for individuals to practice their wrangling and data visualization skills independent of drawing conclusions.

There are screencast videos on youtube how people have used these datasets in creative ways. [Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZyPrP_Yo1BA)

Answer (score 2):

For data science [Kaggle's Learn part](https://www.kaggle.com/learn/overview) provides tutorials, and Kaggle itself provides near-real problems.